# How do I turn off the power to my thermostat?

Tags: electrical, thermostat

I'd like to replace my thermostat with a new one. My current thermostat is one that doesn't have a C-wire and is powered by batteries.

Now, my question is... is there a switch for the power that I need turn off too? I could not find a switch for the thermostat in the breaker box.

I'm assuming just removing the batteries is fine for replacing my thermostat?

Comment: There is usually a 24V transformer in the furnace that powers the thermostat. You should turn the furnace off or you risk shorting the leads and anything from blowing a fuse in your furnace to dammage a control board.

Comment: I have a Carrier FX4CNF. I searched all over the manual online to see if there is a switch but I am not seeing one...

Comment: The 120v breaker that powers the furnace should kill it if there is not a local switch.

Comment: If your return is in ceiling, the switch is in attic.

Answer (score 3):

Simply turning off the breaker that feeds the furnace will turn off the thermostat power as well.

Comment: Depending on the installation, there might be a switch near the furnace (serviceman switch). This can also be used to turn power off to the furnace.